# Everytime i run this query on mysql-workbench i get error

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
 first_table.Name, 
 second_table.Working_hours 
FROM first_table 
FULL OUTER JOIN second_table 
  ON first_table.Member_id=second_table.Member_id;
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `full outer join`.  And, why would you want a `full outer join` in this case anyway?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i was just trying to run mysql query through this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) but it didn't work, thats why i asked here.

Comment: @Fabricator Thanks a lot. And Sorry to bother you, Next time i'll try to search in better way.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`. And the error you get if you try can be misleading.

The error is the result of a [syntax bug in MySQL](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69858). The standard SQL keyword `FULL` is not treated as a reserved word. Using the keyword `FULL` therefore acts like a table alias.

It's as if you had written the query like this:

```
SELECT 
 first_table.Name, 
 second_table.Working_hours 
FROM first_table AS `FULL`
OUTER JOIN second_table 
  ON first_table.Member_id=second_table.Member_id;
```

The error is that `OUTER JOIN` needs either the `LEFT` or `RIGHT` qualifier, but neither is present in this case.